# Why are turbofan-engined Caravelles' engine pylons open at the back?

Tags: aircraft-design, sud-caravelle, engine-pylon

The engine pylons of turbofan-engined Caravelles are open at the very back, looking for all the world like someone'd simply taken a saw and sliced off the rearmost portion of the pylon:

---

[image: Caravelle engine pylon shenanigans]

(Image originally by clipperarctic at [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/23344035@N03/6153753611/), via Russavia at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Finnair_Caravelle_(6153753611).jpg); cropped and annotated by me.)

---

[image: Caravelle Pylon 2: Electric Boogaloo]

(Image originally by André Cros, via Donna Nobot at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:28.08.62_Premiers_pas_Caravelle_Horizon_(1962)_-_53Fi2220.jpg); cropped and annotated by me.)

In contrast, Avon-engined Caravelles (the Caravelle I-VI) have a *non*-apparently-sliced-open style of engine pylon which tapers to a closed trailing edge in the normal manner:

[image: this looks more like it]

(Image by Mattias Björklund (Sgt. Oddball) at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%22Hush_kit%22_on_a_Sud_Aviation_Caravelle.JPG).)

Given that it seems intuitively as though the turbofan-engined Caravelles' chopped-open engine-pylon trailing edges would significantly increase drag (which is generally considered a bad thing unless you can make it so that it only increases drag when you *want* increased drag), why are these Caravelles' engine pylons built like this?

Comment: Openings like that area almost always an exhaust for a heat exchanger.